# Die Tags Rechtschreibung und Orthographie // The tags spelling and orthography

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Zurzeit existieren hier sowohl die Tags [rechtschreibung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rechtschreibung) wie auch [orthographie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthographie). Der eine ist offiziell für Fragen zur Rechtschreibung bestimmter Wörter gedacht ([rechtschreibung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rechtschreibung)), während der andere eher für die dahinterliegenden Regeln gedacht ist. Wie soll mit dieser Parallelität weiter umgegangen werden?

Die Frage ist aus Freundlichkeit in beiden Sprachen gehalten; Antworten in jeder Sprache mögen gleichberechtigt behandelt werden.

Anmerkung: Im deutschen Teil habe ich die deutschen Namen verwendet, die selbstverständlich gemäß unseren Regeln Synonyme ihrer englischen Übersetzungen sind.

---

---

There are two tags concerning spelling that exist on German.SE: [spelling](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) and [orthography](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography). The official distinction is that the former should be used for questions on the spelling of single words while the latter should be used for overarching questions on the rules in the background. How should we handle this parallelity?

This question has been written in both languages out of courtesy. Answers in both languages shall be treated equally.

Comment: Ich habe es umgesetzt. [rechtschreibung], [orthografie], [orthographie] und [orthography] sind jetzt alle Synonyme von [spelling].

Comment: @Wrzl Interessant, dass du die Antwort mit weniger Upvotes gewählt hast, aber was solls; Hauptsache wir haben etwas einheitliches ;)

Comment: Ich habe Deine Antwort nicht so aufgefasst, dass Du Dich für ein spezifisches Tag als Synonym-Ziel ausgesprochen hast, sondern nur für die Zusammenlegung der Tags als solches. Letztlich sind es eh Synonyme und es macht für den Nutzer kaum einen Unterschied, was jetzt das Haupt-Tag ist.

Comment: »Ich schlage deshalb vor, beide Tags unter dem Stichwort [tag:orthographie] zusammenzufassen.« – für mich war das klar … Beim Rest volle Zustimmung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da heute immer seltener Griechisch und Latein gelernt werden halte ich den Begriff "Rechtschreibung" für besser geeignet, als Orthographie, das neue Tag zu werden, weil er für kaum jmd. eine Barriere darstellt.

Answer (score 6):

In meinen Augen ist die Unterscheidung zwischen [rechtschreibung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rechtschreibung) und [orthographie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthographie) künstlich und in der Praxis wenig relevant. Bei der Schreibung bestimmter Wörter werden mit Sicherheit die dahinterliegenden Regeln erwähnt werden, während Antworten, in denen es um die Regeln geht, sicherlich mit Beispielen ausgefüllt werden. Ich schlage deshalb vor, beide Tags unter dem Stichwort [orthographie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthographie) zusammenzufassen.

---

---

In my opinion the distinction between [spelling](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) and [orthography](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) is artificial and not relevant in practice. When asking about a specific word’s spelling, the answer will surely quote the underlying rules while conversely questions on said rules will surely be exemplified by specific word examples. Therefore I propose to merge the tags under the overarching [orthography](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography).

Comment: Mir war die Unterscheidung in den Tag-Beschreibungen erst vor ein paar Tagen aufgefallen und ich habe entsprechend einige Fragen, darunter ziemlich alte, anders eingeordnet. Offenbar richten sich viele Fragesteller nicht danach, sondern wählen intuitiv einen der beiden Begriffe und häufig eben anders als vorgesehen. Daher scheint die Unterscheidung wirklich wenig hilfreich zu sein.